# No output/nothing happens when running Laravel Dusk

Tags: php, laravel, mamp, laravel-dusk

I'm using Laravel's Dusk for browser testing.

Sporadically, when I run `php artisan dusk` nothing happens. No errors, no output, nothing.

To demonstrate the "nothingness", [here's a short video clip](https://www.youtube.com/embed/e1djZMeHYlw?rel=0&showinfo=0).

Same nothingness occurs when running `php artisan dusk -vvv`.

I am able to run individual tests by specifying the file name, e.g. `php artisan dusk /path/to/site/tests/Browser/PagesTest.php`

I've run each of my individual tests this way - thinking maybe one was short-circuiting it - but they all run fine when invoked individually.

Sometimes this will happen, I'll troubleshoot for a while, give up, then come back to it days later and it will just work fine.

Update w/ additional info:

- It's specific to one project; does not happen on a fresh Laravel install

Specs:

- Laravel 5.7.9 / Dusk 4.0.2
- Mac High Sierra 10.13.5
- MAMP Pro 5.1.1 w/ PHP 7.2.8

Comment: Try: `php artisan dusk --debug --verbose`. Do you get any more helpful output?

Comment: Same result - no output/nothing happens

Comment: Do you have a `phpunit.dusk.xml` file in your base path?

Comment: @TravisBritz Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out: **I had two different Browser test files with the same class name.**

It happened when I duplicated an existing test to create a new one and forgot to change the class name.

I was getting no output, but behind the scenes **it was a PHP error**.

I've since learned that if I add the following to `phpunit.dusk.xml`, it will show the error:

```
<php>
    <ini name="display_errors" value="On" />
    <ini name="display_startup_errors" value="On" />
</php>
```

Now, when a mistake like that exists, I get useful feedback:

```
$ php artisan dusk

Fatal error: Cannot declare class Tests\Browser\AccountTest, 
because the name is already in use in /tests/Browser/GroupTest.php on line 30
```

Answer (score 1):

To ensure

```
php artisan dusk
```

Works well, you need to check the followings :

- Have chrome installed on your equipement
- Have the latest update on chrome
- If you get stuck at 100% after changing at least one of the previous point, you need to change the configuration file for dusk to purge his cache, so go to /phpunit.dusk.xml and add a few lines

For example, add these into the  tags :

```
<php>
    <ini name="display_errors" value="On" />
    <ini name="display_startup_errors" value="On" />
</php>
```

Then relaunch

```
php artisan dusk
```

It should do the trick.